# Using AsyncTask with android

Tags: android

My code is ok, no problem.I did not use **onPostExecute()** method. But my code also run and layout show fine. But I want to do use  **onPostExecute** method for showing UI. How can I use **onPostExecute** in my code? Because My code is looping and adding value in listview. So I can not understand how can I use onPostExecute in this code. Please help me !

```
private class AsyncCaller extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {
        ProgressDialog pdLoading = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            //this method will be running on UI thread
            pdLoading.setMessage("\tLoading...");
            pdLoading.show();


        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            //this method will be running on background thread so don't update UI frome here
            //do your long running http tasks here,you dont want to pass argument and u can access the parent class' variable url over here

            try {
                ParseQuery<ParseObject> myObject = ParseQuery.getQuery("AllPost");
                myObject.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
                        for (ParseObject parseObject : objects) {
                            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            // parseObject.getString("post"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            list.add(parseObject.getString("post"));
                             adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                                        R.layout.list_view, list);
                             setListAdapter(adapter);
                        }

                    }
                });

                Thread.sleep(300);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }



            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            //this method will be running on UI thread





            pdLoading.dismiss();
        }

        }
```

Comment: Move `adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                                        R.layout.list_view, list);setListAdapter(adapter);` to `onPostExecute`

Comment: You should drop AsyncTask since findInBackground also starts a new thread for the operation. This way you start two thread.

Answer (score 0):

```
private class WebServiceTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

        public static final int POST_TASK = 1;

        private static final String TAG = "WebServiceTask";

        // connection timeout, in milliseconds (waiting to connect)
        private static final int CONN_TIMEOUT = 3000;

        // socket timeout, in milliseconds (waiting for data)
        private static final int SOCKET_TIMEOUT = 5000;

        private int taskType = POST_TASK;
        private Context mContext = null;


        private ArrayList<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();



        public WebServiceTask(int taskType, Context mContext, String processMessage) {

            this.taskType = taskType;
            this.mContext = mContext;

        }

        public void addNameValuePair(String name, String value) {

            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(name, value));
        }


        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            String url = urls[0];
            String result = "";

            HttpResponse response = doResponse(url);

            if (response == null) {
                return result;
            } else {

                try {

                    result = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent());

                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
                }

            }

            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String response) {

            handleResponse(response);


        }

        // Establish connection and socket (data retrieval) timeouts
        private HttpParams getHttpParams() {

            HttpParams htpp = new BasicHttpParams();

            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(htpp, CONN_TIMEOUT);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(htpp, SOCKET_TIMEOUT);

            return htpp;
        }

        private HttpResponse doResponse(String url) {

            // Use our connection and data timeouts as parameters for our
            // DefaultHttpClient
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(getHttpParams());

            HttpResponse response = null;

            try {
                switch (taskType) {

                case POST_TASK:
                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
                    // Add parameters
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                    response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    break;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                display("Remote DataBase can not be connected.\nPlease check network connection.");

                Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
                return null;

            }

            return response;
        }

        private String inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {

            String line = "";
            StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();

            // Wrap a BufferedReader around the InputStream
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

            try {
                // Read response until the end
                while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                    total.append(line);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
            }

            // Return full string
            return total.toString();
        }

    }
    public void handleResponse(String response) 
    {    //display("JSON responce is : "+response);
        try {

            JSONObject jso = new JSONObject(response);


                  String UName = "hi";

                  if( UName.equalsIgnoreCase("") || UName==null)
                  {
                     display("Project report(s) can not be retrieved.");
                  }
                  else
                  {
//                     int count=Integer.parseInt(UName);
//                     display("Number of Projects have been handling in AFL right now: "+count);
                    list1=new ArrayList<String>();
                    list12=new ArrayList<String>();
                    JSONArray array=jso.getJSONArray("Jobs");
                    JSONArray array1=jso.getJSONArray("Jobs1");
                    for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++)
                    {
                        list1.add(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("branchName3"));
                        list12.add(array1.getJSONObject(i).getString("branchName4"));

                    }
                    itr=list1.iterator();
                    itr1=list12.iterator();
                    while(itr.hasNext()&&itr1.hasNext())
                    {
                         //str1=itr.next()+"\n";
                        todoItems.add(0, itr.next().toString());
                        cad.add(0, itr1.next().toString());
                        aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        a1.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }

                    //tv1.setText(str1);


                  }      
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
            return;
        }

    }
```

use this for example,here i did the Onpost execute

Comment: yah bro I understand but i want for my code.please help me for this code